# Javascript doesnt track DOM changes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

On a web page I have a `script` tag and after some interaction with a page it got modified. I can clearly see that when doing `View Page Source` in a Chrome browser. But I'm not able to track any changes neither with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) nor with regular `getElementsByTagName` accessing the content.

Is there something special about `View Source` (e.g. it sends new request to the server thus obtaining a page with different code) or is there some other place/technique to look for?

An example using MutationObserver

```
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.target.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
      console.log(mutation.type, mutation.target);
    }

  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(document, config);
```

Comment: `it sends new request to the server thus obtaining a page with different code ?` certainly not

Comment: While View Page Source does not send a new request to the server, AFAIK it displays the source code of the page as it was delivered from the server (ie. before any programmatic DOM mutations). You need to use the Elements tab of Chrome DevTools to see the current DOM of the page. (You can open the DevTools from Chrome menu or by selecting Inspect from context menu.)

Comment: There's no `characterData:true` in your config.